# Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get the last time the data was modified in the tables of the database without any duplicating object_ids ,as I was getting 4 of the same `object_Ids` because the `last_user_update field` is present four times for the same `object_id` .I have tried different variations by grouping with `Object_id` ,`max(Object_Id)` and different fields and I still get the same error .
What is the right way to do this ?
This is the error message I'm getting

```
Column 'sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.user_scans' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

    select  max(i.object_id)
                ,S.name
                ,I.last_user_scan
                ,i.user_scans
                ,i.user_lookups
            ,i.last_user_update
                ,i.last_system_scan
                ,i.user_updates 
                ,s.modify_date
    from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats I
    Inner Join sys.objects S
    ON I.object_id = S.object_id
    WHERE type = 'U'

group by S.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the same object_id multiple times because you get a row per index, not a row per object. The point of this DMV is to show you which indexes are getting used more or less than others. So maybe you want:

```
select  I.object_id
            ,S.name
            ,si.name
            ,I.last_user_scan
            ,i.user_scans
            ,i.user_lookups
            ,i.last_user_update
            ,i.last_system_scan
            ,i.user_updates 
            ,s.modify_date
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats I
Inner Join sys.objects S
ON I.object_id = S.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS si
ON I.[object_id] = si.[object_id]
AND I.index_id = si.index_id
WHERE type = 'U';
```

If you really just want the last access and the sum of all activity against a table, without caring about which index(es):

```
SELECT s.name 
            ,MAX(I.last_user_scan)
            ,SUM(i.user_scans)
            ,SUM(i.user_lookups)
            ,MAX(i.last_user_update)
            ,MAX(i.last_system_scan)
            ,SUM(i.user_updates) 
            ,MAX(s.modify_date)
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats I
Inner Join sys.objects S
ON I.object_id = S.object_id
WHERE type = 'U'
group by S.name;
```

These aren't ideal because if you have `dbo.Accounts` and `test.Accounts`, they will get grouped together.